# Is "proc" required with conditional before_action/before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter

Behold, a `before_filter`:

```
class ThingController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_stuff, :if => proc {Rails.env.production?}
end
```

During a recent code review, I was asked, **"Is the `proc` is required for this to work?"** The answer appears to be 'yes', but it's a reasonable question, and I had intended to answer it by referring to the Rails docs or guides or something on the use of conditionals with `before_filter` (now an alias of `before_action`).

I couldn't find any. The [Action Controller Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) mentions `:only`/`:except`, but not `:if`/`:unless`.

Failing that, is there somewhere in the code I can point to that covers this? It's mentioned briefly [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#LC24), but that's more about how `:only` and `:except` are handled, rather than `:if` or `:unless`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Found it on Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks

Turns out a `Proc` isn't always required for it to work.

> the `:if` and `:unless` options, which can take a symbol, a string, a `Proc` or an `Array`.

So in your case you could probably get away with

```
before_action :check_stuff, if: "Rails.env.production?"
```

Finding things in Rails documentation can be a pain sometimes, but at least questions like this make things easier to find over time since StackOverflow is well indexed and has high search rankings.

Comment: Technically, those are ActiveRecord callbacks, rather than ActionController ones, but I imagine the option syntax is the same. I'm not sure if I like eval'd strings better than Proc, but thanks for finding the docs.

Comment: Looks like ActionController and ActiveRecord use the same `ActiveSupport::Callbacks` implementation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html

ActionController does some normalization to convert :only and :except options to the :if and :unless options ActiveSupport::Callbacks expects.

Answer (score 29):

From Rails 5.2 onwards, the current accepted answer is no longer be valid, and passing a string to the conditional will fail.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing string to :if and :unless conditional options is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.2 without replacement.

Going forward, a proc is now the best way to add a conditional like in the original question:

```
class ThingController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_stuff, :if => proc {Rails.env.production?}
end
```

Answer (score 12):

i have done this on my code while ago. I hope that example helps to you. If you can use if statement but that should point to another method like I did here.

```
class Admin::ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :deny_access, :unless => :draft_and_admin?

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  protected

  def draft_and_admin?
    Article.find(params[:id]).draft? && current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

Comment: That's useful to know, but doesn't address my actual question, which is about documentation.

Comment: There will not be documentation about if and unless because people are using condition inside the method

Comment: This is fantastic

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend using staby lambda. If you want know, WHY?
[Please read this](https://dev.to/keithrbennett/why-i-prefer-stabby-lambda-notation-5gcj)

```
class ThingController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_stuff, if: -> { Rails.env.production? }
end
```

which is almost equivalent to Upvote Me's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a method to check the `if/unless` conditions for a `before_action` should be the best way as this way you can easily accommodate any additional changes in the `before_action` conditions easily in future:

```
class ThingController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_stuff, if: :check_stuff?

  def check_stuff
  end

  private

  def check_stuff?
    Rails.env.production?
  end
end
```