# Active Admin, Devise and Pundit (Pundit::PolicyScopingNotPerformedError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, pundit

I have an existing Rails app with `Devise` authenticating the `User` model and `Pundit` authenticating against an `Enrollment` model which links `User` to my `Company` model.  Both `User` and `Company` are in the public schema of the apartment gem.  I don't suspect apartment is part of the issue but I figured I would mention it.

I added Active Admin with the AdminUser class - I want to keep my admin user separate from the app users.

If I try to access `/admin` or `/admin/dashboard` I get:

```
Pundit::PolicyScopingNotPerformedError at /admin/users
Pundit::PolicyScopingNotPerformedError
```

If I try my models like `/admin/users` Pundit seems to ignore the active_admin policies and goes to the main app policies.  In my case the app throws an exception because it's expecting an `Enrollment` vs the `AdminUser`.

If I disable:

```
##/config/initializers/active_admin.rb
  config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::PunditAdapter

##/controllers/application_controller
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:landing, :dashboard], unless: :devise_controller?
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: [:index]
```

It all works but then I lose Pundit etc in my main app.

Here is a gist of my code:

https://gist.github.com/jasper502/4b2f1b8b6f21a26c64a5

Here are the related posts that could find on this issue:

https://gorails.com/forum/using-pundit-with-activeadmin

[How to get Active Admin to work with Pundit after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883386/how-to-get-active-admin-to-work-with-pundit-after-login)

I was looking to disable Pundit all together over in this post ([Can you disable Pundit with Devise and Active Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649465/can-you-disable-pundit-with-devise-and-active-admin/34649998?noredirect=1#comment57047962_34649998)) but it would be nice to just make this work.

**UPDATE**

I have work around but I still don't know if this should work out of the box and I have some weird issue causing all of this.  Gist updated.

I ended up using:

https://viget.com/extend/8-insanely-useful-activeadmin-customizations

and a bit of:

[Documentation for conditional before_action/before_filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368424/documentation-for-conditional-before-action-before-filter)

and a bit of the answer below.  I shoehorned in a filter to force AA to call authorize on the resources and collections inside AA.  Next would be to add the policy scopes but my brain hurts too much now.

I also had to add another filter to bypass authentication on the Dashboard as it's headless.  Seems to work so far.

**UPDATE 2**

Hmmm... I think I spoke too soon.  This all works only if I am logged in as a regular `User` - I if I log out it all falls apart again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@dan-tappin I imagine you already found a similar solution based on your comments but here is what I ended up adding to each of my AA model registrations:

```
#app/admin/user.rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller do
    before_filter :authorize_index, only: :index
    def authorize_index
      policy_scope(User)
    end

    before_filter :authorize_show_edit_destroy, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy]
    def authorize_show_edit_destroy
      authorize resource
    end
  end
end
```

Basically this utilizes the ability to execute in the controller scope using normal rails before_filter syntax to limit the execution with :only. Then because the before_filter happens after the inherrited_resources filters we have access to the "resource" and we can authorize against it like you would normally against any model instance. See: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/1108#issuecomment-14711733

The reason the policy scope is needed in the first place is because a normal pundit installation requires the following in the application_controller.rb

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  include Pundit
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  #before_action :authenticate_is_admin!

  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:index, :dashboard], unless: :devise_controller?
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index, unless: :devise_controller?

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  private
  def authenticate_admin!
    redirect_to new_user_session_path unless current_user.admin?
  end

  private
  def pundit_user
    current_user
  end

  private
  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:error] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
    redirect_to(request.referrer || new_user_session_path)
  end
end
```

It expects a call to policy scope the model for all index actions. Dashboard controller renders the index action by default thus necessitating this before_filter hack.

Comment: Thanks for this. Instead of your first `before_filter` in admin/{resource}.rb, you can modify ApplicationController: `after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index, unless: :devise_or_pundit_controller?` ... `def devise_or_pundit_controller?
      devise_controller? || self.class.name.match(/^Admin/)
    end`

Comment: Nice that is cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just skip the scoping in your Active Admin controller with `skip_policy_scope`?

See the [documentation](https://github.com/elabs/pundit):

> If you're using `verify_authorized` in your controllers but need to
>   conditionally bypass verification, you can use `skip_authorization`. For
>   bypassing `verify_policy_scoped`, use `skip_policy_scope`.

Comment: I could probably do that except that then eliminates the ability to scope entirely and also doesn't resolve the issue where my policies are not being loaded.

Comment: Hmmm... the only way I could seem do do that that is with #1 from https://viget.com/extend/8-insanely-useful-activeadmin-customizations Now I get `Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError` errors.